# CoreDataへsetしたデータがUITableViewに反映されない

Tags: swift, ios, swift5, coredata

CoreDataへsetし、dismiss()で元の画面に戻ったさい、更新されず。再度アプリを開き直すと、表示されます。末尾にソースコードを記載しています。

・質問
　dismiss()した、もしくは画面が戻った後に、UITableViewを最新のCoreData内に格納された情報を表示させたい（UITableViewを更新させたい）。

・やったこと
 - tableview.reload() で更新するか試しましたが、更新されませんでした。
 - 新たに配列を作って、入れ直した配列から情報を取得しましたが、更新しませんでした。

・所感
CoreData自体にデータが入ってはいるので、dismissした際に何か更新する何かをする必要があると考えています。

よろしくお願い致します。

以下がUITableViewControllerです。

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class FriendListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var messageLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var friendListTableView: UITableView!

    private let persistentContainer = NSPersistentContainer(name: "RecommendPresent")

    var friends = [FriendBasicInfo]() {
        didSet {
            updateView()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        doFetch()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        friendListTableView.reloadData()
    }

    func setupView() {
        setupMessageLabel()
        updateView()
    }

   fileprivate func updateView() {
        var hasFriends = false

        if let friends = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects {
            print("fetch count \(friends.count)")
            hasFriends = friends.count > 0
        }

        friendListTableView.isHidden = !hasFriends
        messageLabel.isHidden = hasFriends
    }

    func setupMessageLabel() {
        messageLabel.textAlignment = .center
        messageLabel.text = "You don't have any quotes yet."
    }

    func doFetch() {

        persistentContainer.loadPersistentStores { (persistentStoreDescription, error) in
             if let error = error {
                print("Unable to Load Persistent Store")
                print("\(error), \(error.localizedDescription)")

            } else {
                self.setupView()

                do {
                    try self.fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
                } catch {
                    let fetchError = error as NSError
                    print("Unable to Perform Fetch Request")
                    print("\(fetchError), \(fetchError.localizedDescription)")
                }
                self.updateView()
            }
        }
    }


     fileprivate lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<FriendBasicInfo> = {
        // Create Fetch Request
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<FriendBasicInfo> = FriendBasicInfo.fetchRequest()

        // Configure Fetch Request
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]

        // Create Fetched Results Controller
        let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.persistentContainer.viewContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

        // Configure Fetched Results Controller
        fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

        return fetchedResultsController
    }()

}

extension FriendListViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
         guard let friends = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects else { return 0 }
               return friends.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        guard let cell = friendListTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: FriendListTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? FriendListTableViewCell else {
            fatalError("Unexpected Index Path")
        }

        let friend = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)

        cell.nameLabel.text = friend.name
        cell.friendImageView.image = friend.photo?.toImage()

        return cell

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 80
    }
}


extension FriendListViewController: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        friendListTableView.beginUpdates()
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        friendListTableView.endUpdates()

        updateView()
    }

}
```

以下がCoreDataにデータを入力するViewControllerです。

```
import UIKit
import XLPagerTabStrip
import Eureka
import CoreData
import ImageRow

class InputFriendInforViewController: FormViewController, IndicatorInfoProvider {

    var itemInfo: IndicatorInfo = "Info"
    var friendPhoto: UIImage?
    var friendName: String = ""
    var friendBirthday: Date?
    var friendGender: String = ""


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       form +++

        Section("Friend Information")
            <<< ImageRow(){
                $0.title = "Image"
                $0.sourceTypes = [.PhotoLibrary, .SavedPhotosAlbum, .Camera]
                $0.value = UIImage(named: "noImage")
                $0.onChange { [unowned self] row in
                                self.friendPhoto = row.value!
                            }
            }
            <<< TextRow(){ row in
                row.title = "Name"
                row.placeholder = "Enter Name here"
            }.onChange { name in
                self.friendName = name.value!
            }
            <<< DateRow(){ row in
                row.title = "Birthday"
                row.value = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 0)
            }.onChange {date in
                self.friendBirthday = date.value!
            }
        <<< PushRow<String>(){row in
                row.title = "Gender"
                row.options = ["Male","Female","Other"]
            }.onChange {gender in
                self.friendGender = gender.value!
            }

        +++ Section()
            <<< ButtonRow() {
                $0.title = "SAVE"
            }.onCellSelection {_, _ in
                self.saveInfo()
            }
    }

    // MARK: - IndicatorInfoProvider

    func indicatorInfo(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> IndicatorInfo {
        return itemInfo
    }

    // save friend Info for Core Data
    func saveInfo (){

        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }

        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let friendEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "FriendBasicInfo", in: managedContext)!

        let friendInfo = NSManagedObject(entity: friendEntity, insertInto: managedContext)

        // make unique user ID
        let friendUid = NSUUID().uuidString

        // Image Data UIImage to png Data
        let pngImage = self.friendPhoto?.toPNGData()

        friendInfo.setValue(friendUid, forKey: "userID")
        friendInfo.setValue(pngImage, forKey: "photo")
        friendInfo.setValue(self.friendName, forKey: "name")
        friendInfo.setValue(self.friendBirthday, forKey: "birthday")
        friendInfo.setValue(self.friendGender, forKey: "gender")

        do {
            try managedContext.save()
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `FriendListViewController`では自前の`NSPersistentContainer`を作っているのに対し、`InputFriendInforViewController`の方では`appDelegate.persistentContainer`を使用しています。このように複数の`NSPersistentContainer`が存在する状態だと、Core Dataは一貫性のある動作をしなくなります。`FriendListViewController`のprivateプロパティの`persistentContainer`は削除してしまって、`InputFriendInforViewController`と同様に`appDelegate.persistentContainer`を使うように変更すると、どのような挙動になりますか?

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。上記の対応をしたところ、起動後UITableViewで一覧を表示するために、データを取得しようとすると取得できず、データの一覧が表示出来なくなりました。

Comment: また、エラーログとして次のようなメッセージが出ました。```CoreData: annotation: <NSPersistentStoreCoordinator: 0x600001a3a0c0>: Attempting recovery from error encountered during addPersistentStore: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134081 "(null)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingException=Can't add the same store twice}
Unable to Load Persistent Store
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134081 "(null)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingException=Can't add the same store twice}, The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134081.)```

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。さて、コメント欄では修正すべき点を何もかもお示しするのは難しいのですが、`doFetch()`内の`loadPersistentStores`呼び出しは削除されたでしょうか? Core Data使用にチェックを入れてMaster-Detailのプロジェクトを作成してみると分かりますが、Xcodeが作るテンプレートプロジェクトでは、`loadPersistentStores`を呼ぶのはAppDelegate内で一箇所だけになっています。よほどCore Dataのことを熟知しているので無い限り、「`loadPersistentStores`を呼ぶのはAppDelegate内で一箇所だけ」と言う点は真似しておいた方が良いでしょう。私はEurekaなんてものを使ったことがないので、回答の形では書けませんが、問題点は一つずつ解決していってください。ご質問を編集して、質問の最後に「最新のコード」と「そのコードでの実行結果」を追記されると、より多くの方にあなたの問題を考えてもらえるでしょう。